# Merging the contents of many directories specified by a pattern

Tags: ant

Here is a `dirset`.

```
     <dirset dir="..">
       <include name="**/src/main/java"/>
      </dirset>
```

I would like to now merge the contents of all the dirs identified by this dirset into a common directory -- so `../a/src/main/java/x/X.java` and `../b/src/main/java/y/Y.java` would end up as `x/X.java` and `y/Y.java` in the output.